# Run an application written on Zend Framework in my localhost

Tags: php, zend-framework, composer-php

I think this question is a bit obsolete but I have searched a lot of forums but could not arrive at a solution.

My problem is that, I have the source code of an application written in Zend and wanted it to a different language but before that for a better understanding of the application I wanted to run it on my localhost. I tired installing it from composer.phar file but unfortunately, when I open it on the browser, it just shows the directory structure.

The steps that I have followed are:
1. I copied a source code onto the htdocs folder of my xampp directory.
2. Then I did a `php composer.phar self-update` and `php composer.phar install`.
3. Later, when I tried to hit the folder from the browser, it is showing the folder structure and nothing more.

I wanted to know if I have followed the correct steps. I tried installing the Zend demo application on my localhost and it worked but the samething for this did not.

Do let me know if I have followed the correct steps or if I have missed any.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your vhost should point to the public folder if it doesn't already where the index.php states:

```
// Run the application!
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

Sorry, this should be a comment but i lack the rep.